# ImgurPython ConfigParser error

Tags: python, imgur

I've come back to Python after a couple of years of not having used it. I'm testing the [Imgur Python library](https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython). After a fresh install of Python 2.7.12, I did a quick pip install of ImgurPython, then dragged a small folder of the sample scripts to my desktop for testing.

The auth.py sample script begins with a function that includes:

```
# Get client ID and secret from auth.ini
config = get_config()
config.read('auth.ini')
client_id = config.get('credentials', 'client_id')
client_secret = config.get('credentials', 'client_secret')

client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret)
```

The auth.ini file is in the same folder as the auth.py folder, and contains my client ID and secret. However, when running the script, I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python C:\Users\[REDACTED]\Desktop\imgtest\auth.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[REDACTED]\Desktop\imgtest\auth.py", line 41, in <module>
    authenticate()
  File "C:\Users\[REDACTED]\Desktop\imgtest\auth.py", line 16, in authenticate
    client_id = config.get('credentials', 'client_id')
  File "J:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'credentials'
```

Removing the need to get the credentials from the auth.ini file and placing them directly in the Python script has it run with no error.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, but I could use some assistance in figuring out why python won't read the auth.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a bad format of `auth.ini` file. In my python 2.7, the extraction works totally fine with `ConfigParser`:

```
$ cat auth.ini 
[credentials]
client_id=foo
client_secret=bar
```

In my Ipython:

```
In [1]: import ConfigParser

In [2]: config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

In [3]: config.read('auth.ini')
Out[3]: ['auth.ini']

In [4]: client_id = config.get('credentials', 'client_id')

In [5]: client_secret = config.get('credentials', 'client_secret')

In [6]: client_id
Out[6]: 'foo'

In [7]: client_secret
Out[7]: 'bar'
```